# Value of html from jquery get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to retrieve the value of a text field on a another page on my website (prices.html)

Using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/, how can I accomplish this?

How can I do this?

`var price = $('input:price').val();`  <- the value of price from `prices.html` (i'm not on this page so i need to request it)

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get the value from the previous page (post a form) or from another open tab?

Comment: As a quick note, I don't think `$('input:price')` will work, unless you are using a custom selector extension thingy.

Comment: You can't uset `$.get` to get the value of an input in a form from another page. Try setting a cookie while manipulating the input in `prices.html` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
.load('price.html input[name="price"]', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

I didn't try it out myself, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the last examples on the jQuery get page provides you a clue:

```
$.get("test.cgi", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

Assuming that you get your page correctly, you should get a data payload, which you can then parse to get the price information that you're looking for. Using another example, if you have your data processed as JSON, you can extract data like so:

```
$.get("test.php",
   function(data){
     $('body').append( "Name: " + data.name ) // John
              .append( "Time: " + data.time ); //  2pm
   }, "json");
```

Without more information, it'll be hard to put together a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Before you live prices.html page, will be good to store/transfer (post/get)  input:price in hidden textfield in  new page and than read hidden textfield with jquery